# casting to void* to pass objects to pthread in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads, static-cast

I'm a little confused about how to pass an object to the pthread_create function. I've found a lot of piecemeal information concerning casting to void*, passing arguments to pthread_create, etc., but nothing that ties it all together. I just want to make sure I've tied it all together and am not doing anything stupid. Let's say I have the following thread class:
**Edit:** fixed mis-matched `static_cast`.

```
class ProducerThread {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    ProducerThread(const ProducerThread& x);
    ProducerThread& operator= (const ProducerThread& x);
    virtual void *thread_routine(void *arg) {
        ProtectedBuffer<int> *buffer = static_cast<ProtectedBuffer<int> *> arg;
        int randomdata;

        while(1) {
            randomdata = RandomDataGen();
            buffer->push_back(randomdata);
        }

        pthread_exit();
    }
public:
    ProtectedBuffer<int> buffer;

    ProducerThread() {
        int err_chk;

        pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

        err_chk = pthread_create(&thread, &thread_attr, thread_routine, static_cast<void *> arg);
        if (err_chk != 0) {
            throw ThreadException(err_chk);
        }
    }
    ~ProducerThread() {
        pthread_cancel(&thread);
        pthread_attr_destroy(&thread_attr);
    }
}
```

To clarify, the data in the `ProtectedBuffer` class can only be accessed with methods like `ProtectedBuffer::push_back(int arg)`, which use mutexes to protect the actual data.

My main question is: am I using `static_cast` correctly? And my secondary question is do I need that first line in `virtual void *thread_routine(void *arg)` where I copy the passed void pointer to a pointer to `ProtectedBuffer`?

Also, if I've done anything else that might cause problems, I'd appreciate hearing it.

Comment: Erm, you can't pass member functions to pthread_create, can you? (Unrelated: why would anyone want a thread base class in C++? And polymorphic base classes in C++ should have virtual destructors)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: No, it should be static. (The thread class's `this` can be the argument of the thread routine, providing state for the thread routine. Agreed.)

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920441/the-fouth-parameter-in-pthread-create-function

Comment: @user315052 It can't be a member, period.  Even static.  According to the C++ standard, it must be `extern "C"`, and any linkage specification is ignored on member functions.  (The standard requires a diagnostic, but there are some broken compilers which fail to detect the error.)

Comment: @mathematician1975: the infinite loop was just to illustrate something the thread might do. It will actually be polling a serial port and parsing data, but I haven't implemented that bit, yet. Also, the main thread will be continually emptying the buffer from the other end.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: thanks. That thread clarifies a lot.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Please see my public apology in my answer. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to go this route, I believe you want something like this:

**Edit:** Based on James Kanze's answer, add a separate `activate` method to launch the thread after construction is finished.

```
class GenericThread {
protected:
    GenericThread () {
      //...
    }
    virtual ~GenericThread () {}

    int activate () {
        return pthread_create(..., GenericThreadEntry, this);
    }

    virtual void * thread_routine () = 0;

    #if 0
    // This code is wrong, because the C routine callback will do so using the
    // C ABI, but there is no guarantee that the C++ ABI for static class methods
    // is the same as the C ABI.
    static void * thread_entry (void *arg) {
        GenericThread *t = static_cast<GenericThread *>(arg);
        return t->thread_routine();
    }
    #endif
};

extern "C" void * GenericThreadEntry (void *) {
    GenericThread *t = static_cast<GenericThread *>(arg);
    return t->thread_routine();
}
```

Then, `ProducerThread` would derive from `GenericThread`.

**Edit:** <s>Searching for `extern "C"` in the C++ Standard. revealed no requirement that a function pointer must point to a function with C linkage to be callable by a C library routine. Since pointers are being passed, linkage requirements do not apply, as linkage is used to resolve names. A pointer to a static method is a function pointer, according to C++ 2011 draft (n3242), Sec. 3.9.2p3:</s>

> Except for pointers to static members, text referring to pointers does not apply to pointers to members.

**Edit:** *Mea culpa.* The C library will invoke the callback function assuming the C application binary interface. A function with C++ linkage may use a different ABI than the C ABI. This is why it is required to use a function with `extern "C"` linkage when passing to a callback function to a C library. My sincere apologies to James Kanze for doubting him, and my sincere thanks to Loki Astari for setting me straignt.

Comment: Please leave a comment when downvoting, so I know how to improve the answer. Thanks!

Comment: downvoting without comments is so common: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22935/138817 that requests like that are a waste of time. If the person that down-voted you wanted to leave a comment then they would have done so already.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems with your code.  For starters, I don't
see where the `arg` you are casting is declared, so I can't say whether
the case is appropriate.

Perhaps more importantly, `thread_routine` is a member function, so it
can't be converted to a pointer to a function.  The function passed to
`pthread_create` must be `extern "C"`, so it cannot be a member, period; 
it must be a free function declare `extern "C"`.  If you want to call a
member function, pass a pointer to the object as the last argument, and
dereference it in the `extern "C"` function:

```
extern "C" void* startProducerThread( void* arg )
{
    return static_cast<ProducerThread*>( arg )->thread_routine();
}
```

And to start the thread:

```
int status = pthread_create( &thread, &thread_attr, startProducerThread, this );
```

Just don't do this in a constructor.  The other thread might start
running before the object is fully constructed, with disasterous
effects.

Also, be very sure that the cast in `startProducerThread` is to
*exactly* the same type as the pointer passed into `pthread_create`.  If
you cast to a base class in `startProducerThread`, then be very, very
sure that it is a pointer to that base class that you pass to
`pthread_create`; use an explicit cast if necessary (to the type in
`startProducerThread`, *not* to `void*`).

Finally, while not relevant to your actual question: if
`ProtectedBuffer` has an interface like that of `std::vector`, and
returns references to internal data, there's no way you can make it
thread safe.  The protection needs to be external to the class.

Comment: Good point about the activating in the constructor, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: `ProtectedBuffer` actually uses a deque container internally. It was the subject of a previous question I asked on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640681/thread-safe-way-to-build-mutex-protection-into-a-c-class). How can I make sure that the member functions are returning copies of the data in `ProtectedBuffer` and not references?